# how to sort tuple element first on the basis of key and then on the basis of value

Tags: python, tuples

How to sort a tuple of elements in python, first on the basis of value and then on the basis of key. Consider the program in which I am taking input from the user as a string. I want to find out the count of each character and print the 3 most common characters in a string.

```
#input string
strr=list(raw_input())
count=dict()

#store the count of each character in dictionary
for i in range(len(strr)):
count[strr[i]]=count.get(strr[i],0)+1

#hence we can't perform sorting on dict so convert it into tuple 
temp=list()
t=count.items()

for (k,v) in t:
    temp.append((v,k))

temp.sort(reverse=True)

 #print 3 most common element
for (v,k) in temp[:3]:
         print k,v
```

on giving the i/p -aabbbccde

Output of the above code is:

```
3 b
2 c
2 a
```

But I want the output as:

```
3 b
2 a
2 c
```

Comment: In the sort statement, you just need to sort by key. Something like this: `temp.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)`

Comment: what is your input data in your case?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, this question is not simply about sorting by value, but sorting by `(t[0], t[1])` with different order.

Comment: @sparkandshine you are right, since primarily sorting by value in descending order then secondary by key in ascending order is very much a different problem then just sorting by value.

Answer (score 7):

Sort a list of tuples, the first value in descending order (`reverse=True`) and the second value in ascending order (`reverse=False`, by default). Here is a MWE.

```
lists = [(2, 'c'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'b')]

result = sorted(lists, key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1])) # -x[0] represents descending order

print(result)
# Output
[(3, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'c')]
```

---

It is straightforward to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) 
to count each letter's frequency in a string.

```
import collections

s = 'bcabcab'

# If you don't care the order, just use `most_common`
#most_common = collections.Counter(s).most_common(3)

char_and_frequency = collections.Counter(s)
result = sorted(char_and_frequency.items(), key=lambda x:(-x[1], x[0]))[:3]    # sorted by x[1] in descending order, x[0] in ascending order

print(result)
# Output
[('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

Comment: by applying `sorted` on `count.items()` you don't need to have the `lists` intermediate step.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, I see. `result = sorted(count.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))`. Here, I just use `lists` to show an example.

Comment: well using items `x[0]` would be the letter (key) and `x[1]` would be the occurence so it would actually be `key = lambda x:(-x[1], x[0])` :)

Comment: using `Counter` here will give arbitrary order for letters that occur the same number of time:  `collections.Counter(string.ascii_lowercase).most_common(3)  ->  [('z', 1), ('x', 1), ('w', 1)]`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, thx for pointing out this. I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a general solution for "sort by value descending then by key ascending" you can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

def sort_by_value_then_key(count_dict):
    first_level_sorted = sorted(count_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    for _, group in itertools.groupby(first_level_sorted,itemgetter(1)):
        for pair in sorted(group):
            yield pair


strr=list("aabbccdef")
count=dict()

#store the count of each character in dictionary
for i in range(len(strr)):
    count[strr[i]]=count.get(strr[i],0)+1


temp = list(sort_by_value_then_key(count))

for (letter, freq) in temp[:3]:
    print letter, freq
```

Output:

```
a 2
b 2
c 2
```

since you are using integers @sparkandshine's solution of sorting by the negative number will probably be easier to work with but this is much more generalized.