# Sorting a dictionary by REVERSE VALUE then NON-REVERSE KEY

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing string keys and int values that I want to be sorted. I want it to first be sorted by decreasing value number, then in alphabetical order.

For example if you had a dictionary containing:

```
my_dict = {'zebra':1, 'the':201, 'apple':1, 'chicken':58}
```

The resulting sorted list would contain:

```
{('the', 201), ('chicken', 58), ('apple', 1), ('zebra', 1)
```

Currently I'm using the following:

```
my_list = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0])
```

I get a list sorted first in ascending value order and then in alphabetical.

How can I reverse the values but not the keys? I know you can pass a third parameter `reverse=[boolean]` to the `sorted()` method, but it either does or does not reverse BOTH keys and values. How can sort by just one reversal? Thanks for any help!

Comment: not really duplicate but the "sort by value descending then by key ascending" has answers posted [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513551/how-to-sort-tuple-element-first-on-the-basis-of-key-and-then-on-the-basis-of-val)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just negate the value and use it as primary key:

```
>>> my_dict = {'zebra':1, 'the':201, 'apple':1, 'chicken':58}
>>> sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
[('the', 201), ('chicken', 58), ('apple', 1), ('zebra', 1)]
```

Comment: Simpler than mine; I like it! :)

Answer (score 0):

As sorting is stable in Python, you can simply sort it twice: first by the secondary key, then by the primary key:

```
In [29]: from operator import itemgetter
In [30]: my_dict = {'zebra':1, 'the':201, 'apple':1, 'chicken':58}
In [31]: my_list = sorted(sorted(my_dict.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

In [32]: my_list
Out[32]: [('the', 201), ('chicken', 58), ('apple', 1), ('zebra', 1)]
```

[This documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts) explains stable sorting in Python in more detail.